# Files saved with Ubuntu is not visible in Windows 8

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, filesystem, windows-8

I have dual booted my laptop with ubuntu 12.10 and windows 8. When I download some file via ubuntu (e.g a pdf) and save it on a windows partition(NTFS), I do not see it through windows 8. Even when I set to view hidden files, the files do not appear. But when I boot with Ubuntu I see the file is there.

What is the issue here. This is not a very good experience for me. Please let me know how to fix the issue.

Comment: Where on your Windows 8 partition are you saving the files?

Comment: "I do not see it through windows 8" Seems to me that everything works ... on the Ubuntu side. You probably need to find the answer in Windows and that makes it an off topic question. You might need to ask this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: it doesn't matter where I save. Wherever I save, it is not there

Comment: You disabled the Windows "fast startup" right?  You shouldn't even be able to mount the Windows partition if not, but if somehow that warning wasn't working and you did, it could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, under Windows 8, have you made all files visible? Hidden files?

It may also be due bad handling on the Linux side or bad interpretation of Win 8, so safer would be to use FAT32, like on USB-sticks as Linux is handling that perfectly and more easy than the different versions of NTFS.

Hope my limited software knowledge of Linux, but a bit better under Windows is worth something for you...
;3)